# Is it good practice to use try/catch like Python in Java?

Tags: java, programming-practices, error-handling

I mainly use Python and just started learning Java. For now, I've tried using `try/catch` for basic file read/write as follows

```java
public String[] readFile(String fileName){
  try{
    // read file
  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    return "";
  }
}
```

Is such `try/catch` usage good practice in Java?

Comment: You shouldn't do this in Python either.

Answer (score 1):

The particular way you are dealing with the exception in your example is considered a bad practice:

- you are ignoring the exception and just print it (you then probably will also have a tendency to also ignore the console if your program doesn't crash);
- you are then returning an empty string as a result of reading the file, which doesn't tell you if the file was read successfully but it's empty, or if the operation failed and you just returned empty. If someone else is using your code, they are "in the blind" about what happened.

When doing I/O in Java, you will find you have to deal with a lot of exceptions, which is somehow normal given the many ways that could fail (Java has a lot of checked exceptions, but even in other languages you will deal with similar exceptions although at runtime). It's important to consider these failures in your program and do the right thing or the thing that makes more sense in your program. If swallowing the exception and returning an empty string makes sense, then that's no problem. But in most cases you will discover that is not the right way to go about it.

If you want to read more about bad approaches when handling exceptions, you could see [this Exception-Handling Antipatterns post](http://web-old.archive.org/web/20171029154017/https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983543) and the resources at the end of it (ignore that part with Exceptions and Transactions in EJB and focus on the anti-patterns - even though that adds another example of why you should not simply swallow exceptions: if you are within a database transaction and you code fails, but you swallow the exception, the transaction might not be rolled back, and you risk your application state and your database data to become out of sync).